# I want to restrict multiple user logins but no previous answers are helping me?

Tags: django

I want to restrict multiple user logins like when a user tries to login again i want to give him a error  saying you already have a active session

This is how i am doing it right now

**my middleware.py**

```
class MySessionMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
  
   
        response = self.get_response(request)
        
        
       
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print('here2')
            try:
                user = LoggedInUser.objects.create(user=request.user)
            except: 
                user = LoggedInUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            print(type(user))
            if not request.session.session_key:
                request.session.save()
            prev_session_key = request.user.logged_in_user.session_key
            print(prev_session_key)
            if prev_session_key:
                print(prev_session_key)
                print(request.session.session_key)
                print('here5')
                #check whether old key is same as current
                print('here inside user.session_key')
                if prev_session_key != request.session.session_key:
                    return JsonResponse("you already have a active session kindly logout from that", 
                            status=400, safe=False)
            user.session_key = request.session.session_key
            user.save()
       
        return response
```

**my models.py**

```
class LoggedInUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='logged_in_user', on_delete =models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
```

But this approach is not working as previous session key always comes out to be None , please suggest changes in my approach , i tried many solutions but they didnt  work

**my login view**

```
class UserLoginView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    View for a user to login through 1FA.
    The view provides a post request that accepts a email and password.
    Returns a jwt token as a response to authenticated user.
    """
   
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        """
        POST request to login a user.
        """
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        response = {
            "success": "True",
            "message": "User logged in  successfully",
            "token": serializer.validated_data["tokens"],
            "user_name": serializer.validated_data["user_name"],
        }
        status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

        return Response(response, status=status_code)
```

Comment: show your login view

Comment: I have added the login view

Comment: Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951274/i-want-to-restrict-multiple-user-logins-but-no-previous-answers-are-helping-me/69951421#69951421)

Comment: No its not working as request.user.is_authenticated will have new value corressponding to every new request

Comment: I am using postman can that may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your logic from session middleware, add them in login view.

```
class UserLoginView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    View for a user to login through 1FA.
    The view provides a post request that accepts a email and password.
    Returns a jwt token as a response to authenticated user.
    """

    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        """
        POST request to login a user.
        """

        if (request.user.is_authenticated):
            response = {
                "success": "False",
                "message": "User already logged in!",
            }

            return Response(response, status=400)

        else:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            response = {
                "success": "True",
                "message": "User logged in  successfully",
                "token": serializer.validated_data["tokens"],
                "user_name": serializer.validated_data["user_name"],
            }
            status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

            return Response(response, status=status_code)
```